# jq map object fields from TeemIP IPAM databese to fields for Kea DHCP server

Tags: json, jq

How to transform data about PCs from TeemIP IPAM database, to feed it to Kea DHCP server as reservations with jq.
This is the data I would like to transform

```
{
  "objects": {
    "PC::8": {
      "code": 0,
      "message": "",
      "class": "PC",
      "key": "8",
      "fields": {
        "name": "ntb",
        "macaddress": "50:74:9d:b5:5f:5d",
        "ipaddress_id_friendlyname": "10.1.1.6"
      }
    },
    "PC::7": {
      "code": 0,
      "message": "",
      "class": "PC",
      "key": "7",
      "fields": {
        "name": "pc",
        "macaddress": "00:11:c0:92:ab:0e",
        "ipaddress_id_friendlyname": "10.1.70.70"
      }
    }
  },
  "code": 0,
  "message": "Found: 2"
}
```

to this output

```
{
"hostname": "ntb",
"hw-address": "50:74:9d:b5:5f:5d",
"ip-address": "10.1.1.6"
},
{
"hostname": "pc",
"hw-address": "00:11:c0:92:ab:0e",
"ip-address": "10.1.70.70"
}
```

I've tried something like

```
cat pcs.json |jq '[.[]]|.[]|.[]|.[]|.[]|map(.)|{hostname: .name, hw-address: .macaddress, ip-address: .ipaddress_id_friendlyname}'
```

But I was not successful by any means. I'm total noob with json. Please help.

Comment: You want an array of objects i.e. the final output within `[..]` separated by `,` or a stream of objects (without `,`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to and iterate over the target items using `.objects[].fields`, and construct your objects:

```bash
jq '
  .objects[].fields | {
    hostname: .name,
    "hw-address": .macaddress,
    "ip-address": .ipaddress_id_friendlyname
  }
'
```

```json
{
  "hostname": "ntb",
  "hw-address": "50:74:9d:b5:5f:5d",
  "ip-address": "10.1.1.6"
}
{
  "hostname": "pc",
  "hw-address": "00:11:c0:92:ab:0e",
  "ip-address": "10.1.70.70"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/AG2eGbvxTXF)

This produces a so-called stream of objects (no commas in between). If you rather wanted an array of objects (enclosed in square brackets, and its items delimited by commas), just surround the whole filter with a pair of brackets.